# Best practices to receive html via json

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, npm

I'm trying to retrieve an HTML via JSON and i don't know if i'm implementing the best practice for that...

Here's an example:

```
jsonRequest = [
{
  "id": "123",
  "template": '<div class=\"container\">Hello, guys, i am a json</div>'
}];
```

There's some other way to use it?

Comment: convert the html into base64 and send through JSON

Comment: Angular now sanitizes html content by default, so if you look for something like {{ html | safe }} is not necessary. Check [this link](https://angular.io/guide/security#sanitization-and-security-contexts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if there is really a "best practice" in that case. This depends on multiple factors.

First JSON is just a notation, so as long as you provide a valid String content for the template property it is valid (and best practice)

Second I would treat it differently based on the template size. If it is only such a small html template, I think wrapping it inside a JSON can make sense in some cases.

However if you try to render an entire page with the template, I'd suggest to only provide a link to the template in the property and then fetch the template with this link. This keeps your JSON clean and readable (and a lot easier to debug)

Comment: The idea is to render small content to redirect to a big page, so i think that the strategy that i'm trying to do is enough. Thanks!